# Pointers in C using structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to C programming and I am learning about pointers.
Can somebody please explain what the below code means?

```
struct iphdr {
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    ihl:4,
    version:4;
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
    __u8    version:4,
    ihl:4;
#else
#error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
#endif
    __u8   tos;
    __u16  tot_len;
    __u16  id;
    __u16  frag_off;
    __u8   ttl;
    __u8   protocol;
    __u16  check;
    __u32  saddr;
    __u32  daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
};

struct icmphdr
{
    u_int8_t type;                /* message type */
    u_int8_t code;                /* type sub-code */
    u_int16_t checksum;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            u_int16_t        id;
            u_int16_t        sequence;
        } echo;                        /* echo datagram */
        u_int32_t        gateway;        /* gateway address */
        struct
        {
            u_int16_t        __unused;
            u_int16_t        mtu;
        } frag;                        /* path mtu discovery */
    } un;
};

char datagram[4000];
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) datagram;
struct icmphdr *icmphd = (struct icmphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct iphdr));  // what does this line do?
```

What does this do? Alphabets is the address of an array and we are adding some integer to it. What does it return on typecasting?
Record is some other structure.

Comment: Assuming you are on a platform on which `sizeof(int) == 4`, then `sizeof(struct data) == 54`. The third line will then make `record` contain the address of `alphabets[54]`, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because it is out of bounds of the array. So, in short, your program does not make sense, unless you are relying on some platform-specific behavior.

Comment: I edited the question. Can somebody please explain now?

Comment: @SunilKumarJha the third line has an extra closed parentese.

Comment: @SunilKumarJha if you show the definition of iphdr and icmphdr struct., the it is more clear

Comment: @TomKarzes can you please explain now?

Comment: @SunilKumarJha You've completely changed your post, to the extent that most of the original comments are no longer applicable.  However, alignment is still an issue.  Suppose `datagram` is aligned on an odd byte address.  That's perfectly fine for character data.  But now you're trying to access it as a `struct icmphdr`, which probably requires a 0 mod 4 byte address due to the presence of a `uint32_t` (or `u_int32_t` as you call it).  That results in a misaligned access which will be slow at best, and on some architectures will cause a runtime error.  It's buggy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realy it is not a good practice to start C; but anyway:

> char datagram[4000];

means 4000 elements of 8 bit.

> struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) datagram;

this line tries to cast the address of the first element of the datagram array to a *iphdr* var. As *iphdr* contains 21 * 8bit, so from the first element till 21st element of datagram array will be accessible through *iphdr* structure with *iph* pointer. For example:
`iph->tos` is equal to `datagram[2]`

> struct icmphdr *icmphd = (struct icmphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct iphdr));

this line means a jump from the start of the array till *iphdr* size; So it means that just exactly after the section of the array that is not accessible through *iph* pointer, will be accessible with *icmphd* pointer. As *icmphdr* is 8 byte, so 8 byte will accessible with *icmphdr* pointer. In another language, from the 22th element till the 29th element of the *datagram* array will be accessible through *icmphdr* structure. For example:

`icmphd->code` is equal to `datagram[22]`

`icmphd->un.echo.id` is equal to `datagram[25],datagram[26]`

`icmphd->un.echo.gateway` is equal to `datagram[25],datagram[26],datagram[27],datagram[28]`

`icmphd->un.frag.mtu` is equal to `datagram[27],datagram[28]`

this program tries to map a raw data(*datagram*) to structured data that have a specific meaning. Maybe you received *datagram* from a network, and the sender gave you the structure of that data as (*iphdr* and *icmphdr*)